# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 standard demo certificate - location

Tags: ssl-certificate, weblogic

What is the default demo certificate used by Weblogc 12.2.1.3 and where is it stored?

Under <Oracle_Home>\wlserver\server\lib there are cacerts and DemoTrust.jks

On <adf_domain>\security\ there is no DemoIdentity.jks

So I believe Weblogic is using it's own demo certificate for AdminServer and NodeManager stored in DemoTrust.jks?

While checking keystore using:

keytool -list -v -keystore <Oracle_Home>\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks
there are 2 entries: alias wlscertgencab and alias wlscertgenca

Under Weblogic admin console => domain - configuration - SSL there is Private Key Alias: DemoIdentity and Private Key Location: from Demo Identity Kestore

I would like to know where is the default weblogic demo certificate stored, what is his alias, and how does Admin Server and NodeManager knows which certificate to use(in nodemanager.properties I don't see any certificates/keystores entry)?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

The demo certificate is stored in the DemoIdentity.jks file. This file is located under the security folder of your domain, not in the WebLogic Server installation.
The alias is demoidentity
The default keystore pass phrase is DemoIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase (you will need it with keytool)

Comment: As I wrote above: On <adf_domain>\security\ there is no DemoIdentity.jks

Comment: Is it the issue exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460702/weblogic-12c-nmconnect-command-general-sslengine-problem) ?