# Weblogic 12c, nmConnect command - "General SSLEngine problem"

Tags: ssl, certificate, weblogic, demo

While trying to connect to my NodeManager via wlst command, I am getting this error:
General SSLEngine problem

My Weblogic is using demo cert from DemoIdentity.jks which should be valid (until Sat May 17 21:34:56 CEST 2031). Is my demo certificate ok or not? Or am I looking at wrong certificate?

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\ORACLE\ORACLE
\user_projects\domains\adf_domain\security\DemoIdentity.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: demoidentity
Creation date: 17.05.2016.
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=WEBLADF01, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY, O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, ST=MyState
, C=US
Issuer: CN=CertGenCA, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY, O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, ST=MyStat
e, C=US
Serial number: 555f9e38eadebf32
Valid from: Mon May 16 21:34:56 CEST 2016 until: Sat May 17 21:34:56 CEST 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  CD:DA:9B:01:CC:2D:44:2D:F4:5D:03:80:DC:0A:9F:B7
         SHA1: AF:1F:31:BE:FF:74:42:85:ED:1C:87:3F:6E:D1:6F:21:37:04:C6:72
         SHA256: 4E:0C:82:E5:45:AC:FA:B9:11:9B:CA:A6:9D:43:90:17:F8:91:C9:F2:16:
DD:5F:8E:CE:4D:BA:9E:47:83:3B:34
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 34 38 FD 45 D8 80 CF C7   D2 E8 DF 1D F8 A1 39 B0  48.E..........9.
0010: 11 88 00 6A                                        ...j
]
[CN=CertGenCA, OU=FOR TESTING ONLY, O=MyOrganization, L=MyTown, ST=MyState, C=US
]
SerialNumber: [    40044886 c441ef3b 643a8066 409afca0]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
  Key_Agreement
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 62 95 1A 7B 05 B4 D3 FB   34 3F FB A6 50 14 25 93  b.......4?..P.%.
0010: 35 C4 BE DB                                        5...
]
]
```

Comment: Cabn you post the complete error message including the stack trace if any ?
Thx